# Why do we say Sun curves space and the Earth moves following the geodesic?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

Why do we say sun curves space even if the Ricci Scalar  for a Schwarzchild metric, the solution of Einsteins Equations for the Sun, is equal to zero.

The Ricci scalar for the constant time slice is also zero.

Can we define curvature using a single quantity? If yes then what is it?

Comment: Can you explain the relevance of "The Ricci scalar for the constant time slice is also zero." to the rest of the part of your question?

Comment: Also, a few suggestions for the title: "Why do we say the Sun curves the space?" or "Why do we say the Sun curves the space even if the Ricci scalar is zero?". The geodesic part of your current title is irrelevant to the content of your question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor

Comment: I am not 100% sure about all of the details since I come from a condensed-matter background, but I did once see Penrose talk in Leiden and I believe he said that all of the curvature of general relativity can be separated into two parts: (1) the structure of how the light cones at every point of the space have been tilted, and (2) the gravitational time dilation factor at any given point in space. So there is certainly a scalar field which comes out naturally, but it may leave out how light rays are bent...

Comment: Yes, Ricci scalar for Schwarzschild metric is 0. But it does *not* mean that there is no intrinsic spacetime curvature. Complete information about curvature comes from the Riemann tensor, whose components are not all 0 in Schwarzschild coordinates. If by a single quantity, you mean a scalar, then there are a couple of such invariants. One of them, which uses the Riemann tensor, is the Kretschmann scalar given by $R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$

Comment: The Ricci scalar may be zero, as is the Ricci tensor, but the Riemann tensor from which they both come wont be. Consider an analogy: In electristatics one says the divergence of the electric field is equal to the charge density. That doesn't mean that there is no electric field where the charge density is zero. Likewise the gravity "field" is measured in first derivatives of the metric whereas the Ricci scalar is measured in second derivatives (of course even the first derivatives must locally vanish for geodesic motion)

Answer (score 5):

According to the mathematical definition of the curvature, it represents the commutator of covariant derivative. More precisely, $$[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]A^\rho=R^\rho_{\kappa\mu\nu}A^\kappa$$

Where $R^\rho_{\kappa\mu\nu}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor. It is the *single quantity* that defines (or represents) the curvature of spacetime. For a spacetime to be completely flat at a point means all the components of $R^\rho_{\kappa\mu\nu}$ to identically vanish there. But there are some less strict criteria for differently defined flatness, e.g. if $R^\rho_{\kappa\rho\nu}\equiv R_{\kappa\nu}=0$ then it's called *Ricci-flatness* and if $R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}\equiv R=0$ then it's called *scalar-flatness*. But such kinds of flatness don't imply that the spacetime is not curved. As long as the Riemann curvature tensor has non-zero components the spacetime is curved - which can be verified by making a vector parallel transport along a closed curve and seeing that it doesn't match with what it was originally.

Comment: Just clarifying- does it follow (from Einstein field equations) that in Ricci-flat spacetime, Tmn=(Λc⁴/8πG)*gmn? What are some examples of Ricci-flat spacetimes, and can we create such a (local) spacetime and calculate Λ?

Comment: @A.Ok If $T_{\mu\nu}=\dfrac{\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}}{8\pi}$ then $R\neq 0$ implying $R_{\mu\nu}\neq 0$ - making the space _not_ Ricci flat. For Ricci flat spacetimes, $R_{\mu\nu}$ is simply zero. Tho it follows from Einstein equations that by determining $R_{\mu\nu}$or even $R$ in the vacuum (i.e. when $T_{\mu\nu}=0$), you can calculate the $\Lambda$. The exact relations (that follow from taking trace of Einstein equations) are $R_{\mu\nu}=\dfrac{2\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}}{D-2}$ and $\Lambda=\dfrac{(D-2)R}{2D}$. $D$ is number of spacetime dimensions.

Comment: Isn't $8\pi T_{\mu\nu}=\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ just what you get when you set $R_{\mu\nu}=R=0$ in Einstein's field equation?

Comment: @A.Ok Yes, my bad. Actually it would be wrong to check it that way as we don't know a priori that it would be a valid solution. But yes, we can plug in $T_{\mu\nu}$ to be $\dfrac{\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}}{8\pi}$ and get that $R_{\mu\nu}=R=0$. In the previous comment, I was using the results of Einstein equations without a cosmological constant to argue that if $T_{\mu\nu}\neq 0$ then $R \neq 0$ so that's why that reasoning is wrong. Tho the latter part of my previous comment is correct as you might have checked.